# Compare five Excel workbooks and copying matched data to a new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to compare five workbooks to each other in excel and have matching column data copy the entire rows into a new workbook (FinalReport). eg: If there are 2 to 5 names matched, copy the entire rows to the new Workbook (FinalReport). so if a name matched in 3 workbooks, the report page will have 3 rows for that name (one from each workbook) Also to make each name data rows separated from others, meaning if there are more than 1 name matched in all of the workbooks, each name data bulk to appear as a separate table, The table on the report page should look like the following image: 
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f92HS.png)
The last Col (Copied From) is the page name where the matched name found and copied from.

Here is the code:

```
> `Sub CopyRowsIfNameAppears2ormoreTimes() 
> Application.ScreenUpdating = False 

> '1. The files names are "List1", "Arba_let2", "Expedia1",
> "Expedia2", "Book3" '2. The folder path is:
> Documents\HR_Books\BooksList
> 
> 'assumes headers in row 1 of each workbook
> 'assumes file extensions are .xlsx
> 
> 'variables, path and file names
>     Dim wb As Workbook, wbNew As Workbook, wsNew As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
>     Dim wbNamesArr, myPath As String, wbName As String, newFileName As String, c As String
>     Dim n As Integer, r As Long, i As Long
>     Dim rng As Range, copyRng As Range
>     wbNamesArr = Array("List1", "Arba_let2", "Expedia1", "Expedia2", "Book3")
>     myPath = "C:\GoldDR\Documents\HR_Books\BooksList" & "\"
>     If Right(myPath, 1) = "\" Then myPath = Left(myPath, Len(myPath) - 1)
>      'create new file
>     newFileName = "FinalReport" & Format(Now, "hh mm ss")        
>     Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add
>     wbNew.SaveAs (myPath & "\" & newFileName)
>     Set wsNew = wbNew.Worksheets(1)
> 
> 'open each file in turn
>     For n = 0 To UBound(wbNamesArr)
>         wbName = myPath & "\" & wbNamesArr(n) & ".xlsx"
>         Set wb = Workbooks.Open(wbName)
>         Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
>     'add header row to new file
>         If n = 0 Then ws.Rows("1:1").Copy Destination:=wsNew.Range("A1")
>     'copy sheet values and paste to new file
>         r = ws.Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
>         Set copyRng = ws.Rows("2:" & r)
>         copyRng.Copy Destination:=wsNew.Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
>         wb.Close Next n
>      With wsNew
>     r = .Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'insert temporary working columns
>     .Columns("A:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
> 
> 'insert temporary formulas
>     For i = 2 To r
>         .Range("A" & i).Formula = "=COUNTIF(C2:C" & r & ",C" & i & ")"
>         .Range("B" & i).Value = i
>     Next i
>    
>     c = .Cells(1, wsNew.Cells.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Address(0, 0)
>     Set rng = .Range("A1:" & c).Resize(r)
>      'remove all rows where count of names is not equal to 2 or more
>     rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="1", Operator:=xlFilterValues
>     rng.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
>     rng.AutoFilter
>      'sort by name
>     r = .Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
>     Set copyRng = wsNew.Rows("1:1")
>     Set rng = .Range("A1:" & c).Resize(r)
>     rng.Sort Key1:=.Range("C1"), Header:=xlYes
>      'insert header for each "name" and a blank row in between each name block
>         For i = r To 2 Step -1
>             If i = 2 Then Exit For
>             copyRng.Copy
>             If .Cells(i, 3) <> .Cells(i - 1, 3) Then
>                 .Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
>                 Application.CutCopyMode = xlCopy
>                 .Rows(i).Insert
>             End If
>     Next i
> 
> 'delete temporary column
>     .Columns("A:B").Delete
>      'add borders
>     r = .Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
>     c = .Cells(1, .Cells.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
>     For r = 1 To r
>         If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(r, 1)) Then
>             Set rng = .Cells(r, 1).Resize(, c)
>             With rng.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
>                 .LineStyle = xlContinuous
>                 .Weight = xlThin
>             End With
>             With rng.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
>                 .LineStyle = xlContinuous
>                 .Weight = xlThin
>             End With
>             With rng.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
>                 .LineStyle = xlContinuous
>                 .Weight = xlThin
>             End With
>             With rng.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
>                 .LineStyle = xlContinuous
>                 .Weight = xlThin
>             End With
>             With rng.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
>                 .LineStyle = xlContinuous
>                 .Weight = xlThin
>             End With
>             With rng.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
>                 .LineStyle = xlContinuous
>                 .Weight = xlThin
>             End With
>         End If
>     Next r
>      End With Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'save the file
>     wbNew.Save
> 
> End Sub
```

But the result looks like the following:
[Result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBUMP.png)

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Both images in your question are the same image.

Comment: I fixed it know, Thanks

Comment: Can someone help me please, Thanks

Comment: I just checked your code and it's working fine for me. I was working on worksheets, but it should be fine with workbooks as well. Maybe the problem is specific to your data. Did you try debugging it? Open VBA editor, put text cursor within your sub and keep pressing F8 to run it line by line. You should be able to find which line causes the problem.

Comment: Sorted, Thank You.